# Use Backbone Events To Toggle Collection View Properties Or jQuery.siblings()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

Imagine the following simple model and view:

```
app.Messages = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: function() {
        return {
            message: "an empty message…",
            messageActive: false
        };
    }
});

app.MessageView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: "li",
    template: _.template($("#template").html()),
    events: {
        "click": "open"
    },
    initialize: function() {
        this.listenTo(this.model, "change", this.render);
        this.listenTo(this.model, "message:hide", this.hide);
    },
    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    },
    open: function() {},
    hide: function() {
        this.model.set("messageActive", false);
        this.$el.removeClass("show-message");
    }
});
```

The model is part of a collection and everything is held together by a parent view (simplified for this question):

```
app.AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: "#messages",
    initialize: function() {
        this.listenTo(app.messages, "message:show", this.foo);
    },
    foo: function(model) {
        var open = app.messages.where({messageActive: true});
        open.forEach(function(e, i) {
            if (model != e) {
                e.trigger("message:hide");
            }
        });
    },
```

Only one message of the collection can be active at any given time. This means that as soon as a closed message is clicked, any open message will be closed. The question now concerns the functionality of `app.MessageView.open()`. It could imho either use `jQuery.siblings()` to hide the message of all its siblings and show its own:

```
open: function() {
    this.$el
        .addClass("show-message")
        .siblings(".show-message")
        .removeClass("show-message");
}
```

Personally I think this solution quite elegant, I only dislike that it kind of needs to know that it has siblings. My other implementation would use a custom event that gets intercepted by the parent view (`app.AppView.foo()`) that then calls `app.MessageView.close()` on every open message:

```
open: function() {
    this.model.set("messageActive", true).trigger("message:show", this.model);
    this.$el.addClass("show-message");
}
```

This feels a little more "backbone" to me, but seems a little over-engineered. ;-)

I could event think of a third possibilty where the parent view simply keeps track of the last opened model itself and triggers any close event that is intercepted by the models view (seems manageable but not very backbone-like to me ;-) ). I've already covered quite some blog posts and questions here on SO, but came to no real satisfactory conclusion. Maybe someone can shed some light this specific question.

Comment: Interesting problem. I think your second solution is spot-on. But perhaps it feels over-engineered because the MessageView is both sending and receiving events. Maybe if you make the messageview just listen to model events it wouldn't feel so unsatisfactory. The parentview would just trigger events and the messageview would respond. Makes more sense that way, in my opinion.

Comment: Hold on I'll write up an answer with an example of what I mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** Completely missed the click event on the messageview so revamped my answer.

---

You could trigger a click event on the model whenever the view is clicked, then wait for the parentview to trigger show and hide events on the model.

```
app.MessageView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: "li",
    template: _.template($("#template").html()),
    events: {
        "click": "isClicked"
    },
    initialize: function() {
        this.listenTo(this.model, "change", this.render);
        this.listenTo(this.model, "message:show", this.open);
        this.listenTo(this.model, "message:hide", this.hide);
    },
    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    },
    isClicked: function(){
        this.model.trigger("message:clicked");
    },
    open: function() {
        this.model.set("messageActive", true);
        this.$el.addClass("show-message");
    },
    hide: function() {
        this.model.set("messageActive", false);
        this.$el.removeClass("show-message");
    }
});
```

Your parentview is now responsible of sending the right events to the models whenever one of it's childviews is clicked.

```
app.AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: "#messages",
  initialize: function() {
    this.listenTo(app.messages, "message:clicked", this.foo);
  },
  foo: function(model) {
    var open = app.messages.where({messageActive: true});
    open.forEach(function(e, i) {
        if (model != e) {
            e.trigger("message:hide");
        }
    });
   // Because we retrieved the currently active models before sending this event,
   // there will be no racing condition:
   model.trigger("message:show");
},
```

Perhaps not the shortest way to achieve this sorta thing. But it is completely event driven and customizable.

Comment: I see where this is going and I think I like it. With your suggestion all I need to call `foo` is a click listener in my parent view.

Comment: Well yeah, that was what I was thinking. But then I realized that the model is stored in the MessageView. I edited the answer so that the MessageView emits an event to the model whenever the view is clicked. Perhaps even better. This way the MessageView and it's parentview don't need to know each other, but just respond to events.

Comment: Perfect, awesome answer, thx! I just had to look up how if events are added to the prototype of a view (and thus shared by all view instances) or not because I'll end up with a lot of those messages and wouldn't want to have individual instance events.

Answer (score 1):

As a heads-up, I ended up with a slight variation of the accepted answer. Instead of triggering custom events, the views now listen to the change of the models `messageActive` attribute and act accordingly.

```
app.MessageView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: "li",
    template: _.template($("#template").html()),
    events: {
        "click": "isClicked"
    },
    initialize: function() {
        this.listenTo(this.model, "change:messageActive", this.showMessage);
    },
    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON())).addClass("sprite");
        return this;
    },
    isClicked: function() {
        this.model.set("messageActive", true);
    },
    showMessage: function(model, value) {
        this.$el.toggleClass("show-message", value);
    }
});

app.AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: "#messages",
    initialize: function() {
        this.listenTo(app.messages, "change:messageActive", this.hideMessages);
    },
    hideMessages: function(model, value) {
        if (value) {
            var open = app.messages.where({messageActive: true});
            open.forEach(function(e, i) {
                if (model != e) {
                    e.set("messageActive", false);
                }
            });
        }
    },
```

Comment: Not bad, I like it. No events like 'click' flying around on the model is closer to what a model should do. I think this is the most backbone-ish way.